# With NAnt, How to use C# 3.0 compiler while targetting .NET 2.0 runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, c#-3.0, nant

I'm using NAnt 0.85 to build a legacy project. The script itself uses the **`csc` task** (not the `msbuild` task) and works fine.

The project is on its way to migrating over .NET 3.5. We already use VS2008, and C# 3.0, while still targeting .NET 2.0 framework runtime.

Now the problem occurs when we want to upgrade our NAnt scripts, to compile C#3.0 code using csc task.

I managed to compile C#3.0 code with NAnt, by modifying the nant.exe.config to add the net-3.5 framework section, but still, I can't figure a way to ensure that resulting assemblies will execute on .NET 2.0 runtime.

**More problematic** : if I'm using LinqBridge to leverage Linq without System.Core and .NET 3.5 runtime, the csc task fails and gave me an error message indicating that all linq-related calls are ambiguous. In fact, NAnt csc task seems to automatically reference `System.Core.dll`, which causes a conflict with the only reference I effectively added to the `<references>` section, under the csc task: `LinqBridge.dll`.

Do you now how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing on .NET 2.0 is mostly just a case of making sure you don't add a reference to any .NET 3.5-specific libraries. There are other subtleties where new types (e.g. `DateTimeOffset`) have been added to .NET 2.0 SP1 in existing libraries, but that's a different matter.

I *suspect* the LinqBridge problem is due to `csc` using the default response file. It's possible that specifying

```
noconfig="true"
```

will fix this. The documentation states that `noconfig` "Instructs the compiler not to use implicit references to assemblies" which sounds like what you want.

Comment: The noconfig="true" actually solved my problem. What I consider weird, thought, is that System.Core.dll is handled as a "default" dependency by the csc task when noconfig is false. In VS2008, and generally speaking in a csproj, it must be added manually if needed, which makes sense to me. It's not like say, mscorlib.

Comment: A lot of assemblies are in there - it's handy when compiling test programs from the command line. Look in csc.rsp to find out the defaults.