# Existing same reference on different dlls in .NET4.0

Tags: .net, reference, linqbridge

I added a reference (LinqBridge.dll) to my existing project and the references are conflicted like below.

> Error 74 The type 'System.Action' exists in both 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' and
>   'G:\Projects\Test1\Test.UI\Bin\LinqBridge.dll'    G:\Projects\Test1\Test.UI\App_Code\Tools\UrlMap.cs  50  88  G:...\Test.UI\

What is the best way to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance,

**I found something related on this issue but I didnt undestand what exactly I should do.**

[With NAnt, How to use C# 3.0 compiler while targetting .NET 2.0 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776489/with-nant-how-to-use-c-3-0-compiler-while-targetting-net-2-0-runtime)

[Reference 2 dlls using the same namespace in vb.net 3.5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521359/reference-2-dlls-using-the-same-namespace-in-vb-net-3-5-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you [etern aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). This allows you to define fully-qualified types when the project is compiled.

> Go to Solution Explorer. Expand the References tab of your project so
>   that you can see the list of referenced assemblies. Click on the
>   assembly that you wish to assign an alias name. Now look in the
>   Properties Window for the "Aliases" property. Notice that the default
>   value is "global". Change it to anything that you wish.

In code you would reference the namespace using the full-qualified namespace, using the alias.

```
using linqBridge::System.Action;
```

In essence this uses the `/r` switch on the command line when the project is compiled.

```
/r:linqBridge=LinqBridge.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign an [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) to your reference to LinqBridge.dll and refer to its types in your program through that alias, e.g. `bridge::LinqBridge.Types.Foo`, or with a using directive like

```
using LinqBrigdeTypes = bridge::LinqBridge.Types ;
```